# How to train machine learning with strings?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have made input data for machine learning as csv file . The data are 2D arrays input and label
Example

[[55:32:1:23:41:243:255:11:182:192:231:201],"play"]

[[23:222:225],"talk"]

[[23:132:215:111:29:192],"talk"]

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [55:32:1:23:41:243:255:11:182:192:231:201] | play |
| [23:222:225] | talk |

I tried to train using the follwing code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
import io

data = pd.read_csv('./newTest4.csv',  header=None)
data_features=data.copy()
data_labels=data_features.pop(0)
data_features=np.array(data_features)
data_labels=np.array(data_labels)
data_labels 


data_model=tf.keras.Sequential ([
layers.Dense(64),
layers.Dense(1)
])
data_model.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam())


data_model.fit(data_features,data_labels,epochs=100)
```

But the output was

```
UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
     [[node mean_squared_error/Cast (defined at <ipython-input-18-ce25e735eaa4>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1561]
Function call stack:
train_function
```

Comment: You cannot use `strings` as inputs to `ML` or `DL` models, you have to encode the strings into vectors of numbers using different techniques available and then use them as inputs to your model.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way that the model can predict the output. If you have a fixed amount of strings that you want to predict, you have to map each unique string to a binary variable.

An example is a 2-dimensional vector where the first dimension represents "play" and the second dimension represents "talk".

Your data then looks like this:

[[55:32:1:23:41:243:255:11:182:192:231:201],[1,0]] # "play", no "talk"

[[23:222:225], [0,1]] # no "play", "talk"

Now, the model can learn to predict whether the output is [1,0] (play) or [0,1] (talk).

This representation is called one-hot encoding, you can read about it in [this blogpost](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/)!

Comment: Won't this work with categorial data more ? I have different arrays representing the same activity which is talk for example won't this make it not work properly ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot train a model on categories as strings. Rather you encode each string as a unique integer value.

There is a blog post about how to encode categorical data. Check [3 Ways to Encode Categorical Variables for Deep Learning](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-prepare-categorical-data-for-deep-learning-in-python/).